# Implementing pull Down to Referesh

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How would you implement a pull-down to refresh in Flutter app that gets data from a collection in Firestore preferable using a `StreamBuilder` or a `FutureBuilder` and displays it in a `ListView` ?

Comment: Is this related to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525982/streamcontroller-with-firestore
Also, great help already exists in stack overflow for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132896/how-to-refresh-or-reload-a-flutter-firestore-streambuilder-manually and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49493964/pull-down-to-show-search-bar-in-flutter

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you for the references. I will look into them

Comment: That helped very much. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using information from here. [How to refresh or reload a flutter firestore streambuilder manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132896/how-to-refresh-or-reload-a-flutter-firestore-streambuilder-manually)

I added the Refresh indicator and made the my stream get its data from a function see code below.

```
  var stream;

  @override
  void initState() {
     setState(() {
  stream = mouvesStream();
});

  super.initState();
 }

     Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream() {
      return Firestore.instance.collection(_locationState).snapshots();
     }

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error);
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            List aList = new List();
            aList.clear();
            for (DocumentSnapshot _doc in snapshot.data.documents) {
              Model _add = new Model.from(_doc);
              aList.add(_add);
            }
            return TabBarView(
              children: <Widget>[
                RefreshIndicator(
                  onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: aList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Card(aList[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              ],
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
                child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
          }
        })));

       }
```

Comment: Nice implementation, many I ask how you've handled the Future<void> return warning/error from the `_handleRefresh` method? Thanks